# unable to access ec2 ubuntu instance: needpriv 0

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, nginx

**Description:**

I am currently running `nginx` + `nodejs` on a `ubuntu` ec2 instance. I have an elastic ip and have the `nginx` point all `:80` traffic to `/`.

I `ssh` with `.pem` file security. This is my only instance running. This is the error message I get when I attempt to `ssh` into the instance:

```
OpenSSH_4.6pl, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to *elastic ip* [*elastic ip*] port 22
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file *.pem file location*
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '------BEGIN'

...
```

**Disclaimer:**

I am not unable to change anything on my instance (AFAIK). I had been using this `.pem` key for 4 days before this started happening.

Comment: what is the *specific* ssh command you are running? In other words, how do you reference the keyfile? What is the first line of the `.pem` file- certainly it is `-----BEGIN`, but what's the rest of the line?

Comment: Can you add full debug output.